# Practical use of delayed background job when dealing with many users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, background, queue, delayed-job

When a background job starts, it's sent to the back of a queue where a worker handles it; a task clears and the other starts. I think I've got this one right except I don't understand the practical side of it in some cases. Sure, if you're a company sending out 15,000 newsletters once a week using a delayed job makes perfect sense. But when you have an application of even 100 users, in which some task is long enough to need background work (like sending/fetching emails that might take a minute) then each user will have to wait in line while another user gets cleared (in case there's a single worker).

This is the part I'm not sure I'm getting right. I'm talking about the *same* job, but individually for each user. Does that count as a job per user? If I have 100 users, do I need to keep 100 workers for each one's process to not get tied up?

I've tried using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to simulate that, and indeed when I sign in with a different account I have to wait until another user's email gets sent until mine is. While the plugin is swift and simple to work with, I think it's not the right approach here.

I've also tried using Ajax, but since it's an HTTP request it ties up the browser in loading mode until it gets a response from the server (even with `async: true`). Not sure if I ruled this one out too quickly, but I was sortof looking for a more elegant server solution.

Is there a way to achieve a background job like this? (I've heard of different, mostly commercial solutions promising little waiting time, but I'm interested in completely eliminating the queue between users). If not, is there a method to make an ajax request without waiting for a response? I realize my questions are both drastically different but both seem like an appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) is a background processing engine that can support multiple queues.

Ways you could use this:

1. Group your tasks into queues that make sense on their priority. If you need fast response times, use it in a 'foreground' queue. Slow? (like sending/receiving emails) can be in the 'background' queue
2. Have one queue per user (you will need to have many many workers for this)

This SO question also gives a way to [use delayed_jobs with multiple queues/tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015762/use-delayedjob-to-manage-multiple-job-queues)

Comment: Thanks for the sources. Resque seems a little more heavy duty than I need right now, especially b/c of the overhead of installing redis etc. I've been using delayed_job like I said and have loved it, so using multiple queues with dj could possibly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of delayed_job and other message queues is to asynchronously process jobs outside of your core application. I always use a queue for sending email since I'm relying on an outside application (sometimes a third-party API like gmail) to send them and I can't guarantee available and operating efficiency.

So for your use case, even with very few users, I highly recommend offloading emails to delayed_job. This will speed up your front end (ajax) and will also give you retries upon failure. You could spin up multiple workers to process the queue, but it shouldn't be necessary with your numbers unless your calls to send mail are taking a really long time (more than a couple seconds?).

And yes in most situations I'd create separate jobs for each user even though the message might be identical. The only time I'd process them all together would be if the email application / API has bulk sending and you can reduce the number of calls significantly by sending a large payload in a few calls.

Comment: I'm sending and receiving email. I.e. it takes about a minute, that's why I was looking for a solution that is both inexpensive and wouldn't queue up users.

Comment: Can you separate out the send and receive to separate jobs? 1 minute per job seems really long. Experiment with multiple DJ processes until you're happy with the performance. It sounds like you're looking for a multi-threaded solution, but that's actually kind of complicated in Ruby. A multi-process (multiple DJ workers) solution should work fine imo. Also I think you might be a little confused about what Queue means. There's nothing inherently slow about a queue. All you're doing is sending the work to an async process so that you can immediately respond to your users (http response).